# c ++ const tchar *m_pvariable

Tags: c++

```
        // test.h file
      class test
{ test();
 ~test();
public:
 const tchar* m_pvariable;
  struct values{
   const tchar* value1;
   const tchar* value2;
   };
```

};

```
    // test.cpp file
   #include "test.h"

    test::test():m_pvariable(), struct() // default value
    {
    }
    test::~test()
   {}

    void test::function(int num)
    {
    if ( num == 1)
    m_pvariable = "yes";
    else 
    m_pvariable = "No";

    values.value1 = m_pvariable;
    }
```

Problem:   The default assignments are working fine for my other code, but how should i be assigning the tchar values to the pointer??

Comment: This _code_ is invalid. `struct.member` is an error, `struct()` is an error, `class::function` is an error, `constructor:m_pvariable()` is a typo. Also, you can't just assign string literals to pointers like `m_pvariable = "yes";`.

Comment: "is this concept valid"? Which concept? what are you talking about? Please ask a very specific question.

Comment: actually the names of the data types and structs are just example. I wanted to know how do i assign a const tchar* member variable (m_pvariable) to multiple strings according to the value i receive. thank you

Comment: I don't get this. Please [edit] the question to provide a [mcve]. If that proves to difficult, get a good C++ book and read it carefully. You should probably do the latter either way.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, changes are done

Comment: @Marcus Müller: I have made changes

Comment: @ForceBru: changes are done

Comment: Ok, you're still not explaining what you want to do in the bigger picture. You edited and informed us about your edit, but didn't even manage to properly format the code. Also, you were, rightfully, asked to deliver a MVCE by @BaummitAugen. And did you read that page he linked to or give us a verifiable example? No, you did not. So I'm not willing to sink any more time in this.

Comment: Also, consider using Boolean variables rather than the text of "yes" and "no".  Text strings are more difficult to use than Boolean variables.

Answer (score 1):

The topic you are talking about is called *mapping* or *associating*.  You are *mapping* a number to a string.

There are many solutions to this:
1) `switch` statement.
2) `std::map`
3) `std::vector<std::string>`
4) Array
5) table lookup.

You could also use `if`-`else` statements, but that gets ugly.

### The `switch` statement

Example:

```
int selection;
std::string text;
switch (selection)
{
  case 1: text = "Yes"; break;
  case 2: text = "No"; break;
  default: text = "unknown"; break;
}
```

### Mapping (associating)

Example:

```
std::map<int, std::string> table;
table[1] = "Yes";
table[2] = "No";
int selection;
//...
std::string text = table[selection];
```

### The Vector

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> table = 
{ "Unknown", "Yes", "No"};
int selection = 1;
std::cout << "You chose " << table[selection] << ".\n";
```

### The Array

Example:

```
const char * table[] =
{"Unknown", "Yes", "No"};
std::cout << "Text for 2 is " << table[2] << ".\n";
```

### Table lookup

Example:

```
struct Entry
{
  int key;
  char * value;
};
static const Entry table[] =
{
 {1, "Yes"}, // Associate 1 with "Yes"
 {2, "No"},  // Associate 2 with "No"
};
static const unsigned int table_size =
sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]);
std::string Lookup(int key)
{
  std::string text = "Unknown";
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
  {
    if (table[i].key == key)
    {
      text = table[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

### Summary

Each solution has its advantages and disadvantages.  For example the Table Look can be expanded by adding to the table without changing the code; but may be too much code for small quantities of associations.  The `switch` may be good for small quantities, but a maintenance nightmare for large quantities or changing quantities.  Keep them as tools in your toolbox and use as you see fit.

Comment: I want to know whether the string assignment is true or not?

Comment: A string assignment is neither true nor false.  Please clarify.  Are you *comparing* strings for a value?  Are searching a *container* for a string?

Comment: You can compare strings, such as `bool result = test_string == "frog";`

Comment: thnx for the reply. one more thing, can u tell me what could be the problem in my code? with respect to const tchar*

Comment: The problem is you are using character arrays.  Look for `std::wstring` or you could use `std::basic_string<tchar>`.  Fundamentally, you are using pointers to arrays.  So when you assign pointers, you are not copying the contents of the string; only telling the pointer where to point to.  If you insist on using pointers, research "smart pointers".